# How to convert image file to svg format with path attributes?

Tags: image, svg, image-conversion

I want to convert image files into .svg format.
I used bunch of tools out there but they gave us with this format

```
<svg ... >
<image
 xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAT
....
```

But I want to have svg file with path attributes.
Any recommendation would be great help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really a programming question, but a quick answer is inkscape, the has a function called 'Trace Bitmap' to turn  a raster image such as the png you mention into paths.